# Cylinder Snapping into place during Quaternion.RotateTowards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I am trying to do is have a pillar in the center of a scene, and what i think is happening is the quaternion.RotateTowards is receiving a different starting/initial quaternion than the action which is causing it to snap/teleport into a different location which then starts to move to the next. I thought it may be because i'm misunderstanding how quaternions are handled in unity, so i've tried messing with normalizing it, but i can't seem to get any change on the teleport.

The goal is to attach this scrip to a simple 3D cylinder and have it wobble basically, where there will be a player on top of it trying to stay on it. However I can't seem to figure out why it is teleporting and was hoping for a second set of eyes.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformWobble : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeDelay = 0;
    public float rRange = 0.5f;
    public float maxRotation = 20.0f;
    public float rotRate = 0.05f;

    private bool wobble = false;
    private Vector3 randomRotation;
    private Quaternion rotation;
    private Quaternion destination;
    private float x, y, z;
    private bool inPlace;

    private void Start()
    {
        randomRotation = new Vector3();
        inPlace = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (inPlace)
        {
            destination = RotateRandomly();
            inPlace = false;
        }

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, destination, rotRate * Time.deltaTime);
        
        if (transform.localRotation == destination)
        {
            inPlace = true;
        }
    }

    //This will grab the rotation of the object and move it randomly, but won't exceed maxRotation;
    Quaternion RotateRandomly()
    {
        randomRotation = new Vector3(Random.Range(-rRange, rRange), Random.Range(-rRange, rRange), Random.Range(-rRange, rRange));
        rotation = transform.localRotation;

        x = rotation.x + randomRotation.x;
        if(x >= maxRotation && x <= 360 - maxRotation) { x = rotation.x; }

        y = rotation.y + randomRotation.y;
        if (y >= maxRotation && y <= 360 - maxRotation) { y = rotation.y; }

        z = rotation.z + randomRotation.z;
        if (z >= maxRotation && z <= 360-maxRotation) { z = rotation.z; }

        return new Quaternion(x, y, z, transform.localRotation.w);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quaternion calculations are incorrect: quaternions do not hold angles, instead, they hold the *representation* of a rotation about an axis. I emphasized "representation" because it is a little complicated...

The `x`, `y`, `z` components of a quaternion hold the rotation axis unit vector scaled by the sine of the half angle of rotation. The `w` component holds the cosine of the half angle. That is...

```
// NOTE: rotationAngle is in radians rather than degrees
Quaternion MakeQuaternion (Vector3 rotationAxis, float rotationAngle)
{
    float c = Mathf.Cos (rotationAngle / 2);
    float s = Mathf.Sin (rotationAngle / 2);
    Vector3 v = rotationAxis.normalized * s;
    return new Quaternion (v.x, v.y, v.z, c);
}
```

Now, the tricky part for your problem is coming up with the rotation axis and angle for the desired effect.

One solution (if you wish to stick to Euler angles) is to compute quaternions for each Euler rotation and then combine them:

```
Quaternion EulerToQuat (float XAngle, float YAngle, float ZAngle)
{
    Quaternion X = MakeQuaternion (Vector3.right, XAngle);
    Quaternion Y = MakeQuaternion (Vector3.up, YAngle);
    Quaternion Z = MakeQuaternion (Vector3.forward, ZAngle);

    // combine the rotations such that the object is first rotated about the Z axis,
    // then about the Y axis, then the X (ie, reverse order of multiplication).
    // Reminder: quaternion multiplicate is not commutative: order matters, so if this
    // is not the order you want, just siwtch things around
    rotate X * Y * Z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FixedUpdate` doesn't get called every render frame, only on physics frames. You need a way to tell Unity to have each frame showing the rotation change, rather than only updating the rendering when the physics frame has just run.

That is what [`Rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) is for. Cache a reference to the `Rigidbody`, calculate the new global rotation it should have, then call `MoveRotation`:

```
    private Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        randomRotation = new Vector3();
        inPlace = true;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // ...
   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (inPlace)
        {
            destination = RotateRandomly();
            inPlace = false;
        }

        Quaternion newLocalRot = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, 
                destination, rotRate * Time.deltaTime);

        Quaternion newGlobalRot = transform.parent.rotation * newLocalRot;

        rb.MoveRotation(newGlobalRot);
        
        if (transform.localRotation == destination)
        {
            inPlace = true;
        }
    }
```